# Off set a kapacitor batch query

Tags: influxdb, kapacitor

I'm trying to off set my kapacitor query to look for a period of 5 mins but start 10 secs in the past. so the query would be for (now - 10s) to (now - 5m10s). This is to offset the the delay in data.

```
dbrp "telegraf"."Raw"
var process_load = batch
  |query('''SELECT sum("ProcessTime")
    FROM "telegraf"."Raw".Document
    WHERE ("Application" = 'AMP' AND "Environment" = 'test' )
  ''')
    .period(5m)
    .every(10s)
    .groupBy( 'GroupID' , 'Thread' , time(5m))
  |alert()
   .stateChangesOnly()
   .warn(lambda: "sum" > 90000)
   .crit(lambda: "sum" > 240000)
   .log('/tmp/document.test.log')
```

Currently the influxdb is getting it's data from telegraf but the delay is causing the query to send a warning message even when it should be at critical. currently it sends an warning and a critical switching between the two. It should get a critical and then stay there until a document thread stops.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue I needed to add the .align() and the .aligngroup() to the query node